# Filter Nested Array Items CosmosDb

Tags: nosql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is it possible to filter array items in CosmosDb? for example I just need customer info and the first pet(in an array)

Current result:

```
[
{
    "CustomerId": "100",
    "name": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "pets": [
        {
            "id": "pet01",
            "CustomerId": "100",
            "name": "1st pet"
        },
        {
            "id": "pet02",
            "CustomerId": "100",
            "name": "2nd pet"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Expected:

```
[
{
    "CustomerId": "100",
    "name": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "pets": [
        {
            "id": "pet01",
            "CustomerId": "100",
            "name": "1st pet"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ARRAY_SLICE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-slice) function.

SQL:

```
SELECT c.CustomerId,c.name,c.lastName,ARRAY_SLICE(c.pets,0,1) as pets 
FROM c
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "CustomerId": "100",
        "name": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "pets": [
            {
                "id": "pet01",
                "CustomerId": "100",
                "name": "1st pet"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```